# Como exportar footer corretamente com primefaces extensions

Tags: primefaces, microsoft-excel, jsf-2.2

Uso JSF 2.2 e Primefaces 5.0

Utilizando o primefaces Extensions para exportar, em único arquivo excel, três tabelas de um sistema, estou tendo problema com as informações exportadas: O footer de tabelas com colunas dinâmicas, renderizadas em página conforme tratativa no bean e uso de variáveis boolean (utilizadas nos rendere) não estão sendo exportados como desejado (mesmo visual da tela).

Vide imagem:

---

[image: Tela e Arquivo Exportado]

---

Segue abaixo o código da página:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
```

Painel de Controle - Sistema de Notificação de Eventos

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">

    <ui:include src="/paginas/admin/includes/topo.xhtml" />

    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <h:form id="cadastro" prependId="false" styleClass="formCadastro">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel colspan="1" value="ANO:" for="ano" />
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:spacer width="5" height="10" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="ano" value="#{relatoriosMB.ano}"
                        required="true" requiredMessage="É obrigatório informar o Ano.">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selecione..." />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{relatoriosMB.listaAnos}" var="intAno"
                            itemLabel="#{intAno.intValue()}"
                            itemValue="#{intAno.intValue()}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:message for="ano" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <p:outputLabel colspan="1" value="MES INICIAL:" for="mesIni" />
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:spacer width="5" height="10" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="mesIni" value="#{relatoriosMB.mesIni}" required="true" requiredMessage="É obrigatório informar o Mes Inicial">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selecione..." />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="JANEIRO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="FEVEREIRO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="MARÇO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="ABRIL" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="5" itemLabel="MAIO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="6" itemLabel="JUNHO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="7" itemLabel="JULHO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="8" itemLabel="AGOSTO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="9" itemLabel="SETEMBRO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="10" itemLabel="OUTUBRO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="11" itemLabel="NOVEMBRO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="12" itemLabel="DEZEMBRO" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:message for="mesIni" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <p:outputLabel colspan="1" value="MES FINAL:" for="mesFim" />
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:spacer width="5" height="10" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="mesFim" value="#{relatoriosMB.mesFim}"
                        required="true"
                        requiredMessage="É obrigatório informar o Mes Final">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selecione..." />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="JANEIRO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="FEVEREIRO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="MARÇO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="ABRIL" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="5" itemLabel="MAIO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="6" itemLabel="JUNHO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="7" itemLabel="JULHO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="8" itemLabel="AGOSTO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="9" itemLabel="SETEMBRO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="10" itemLabel="OUTUBRO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="11" itemLabel="NOVEMBRO" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="12" itemLabel="DEZEMBRO" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:message for="mesFim" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <br></br>
            <p:commandButton value="GERAR RELATÓRIO" action="#{relatoriosMB.gerarRelatorioTipoClassificacao}" update=":edicao:dataTableAnual, :edicao, :cadastro"/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <p:panel header="Exportar PDF e Excel" rendered="#{not empty relatoriosMB.listaAnual}" style="width: 300px">
                <p:commandLink id="pdf" ajax="false">
                    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/icones/PDF-icon.png" width="50"/>
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="false"
                        target="#{exporterController.customExporter}" />
                    <pe:exporter type="pdf" target=":edicao:dataTableAnual,:edicao:dataTablePeriodo,:edicao:dataTableIncidentePeriodo"
                        fileName="TipoClassificação" datasetPadding="3" />
                </p:commandLink>
                <p:spacer width="20" />
                <p:commandLink id="xls" ajax="false">
                    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/icones/excel-icon.png" width="50" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="false"
                        target="#{exporterController.customExporter}" />
                    <pe:exporter type="xlsx" target=":edicao:dataTableAnual,:edicao:dataTablePeriodo,:edicao:dataTableIncidentePeriodo"
                        fileName="TipoClassificação" datasetPadding="3" postProcessor="#{managerexcel.postProcessXLS}"/>
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <h:form id="edicao" prependId="false">
            <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" globalOnly="true" escape="false" />
            <p:dataTable id="dataTableAnual" var="linhaAnual"
                value="#{relatoriosMB.listaAnual}" editable="true"
                draggableColumns="true"
                rendered="#{not empty relatoriosMB.listaAnual}"
                widgetVar="tableClassAnual"
                filteredValue="#{relatoriosMB.filteredAnual}"
                emptyMessage="Não existem registros Anuais."
                resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true">
                <f:facet name="header" style="text-allign:center">
                    Tabela Tipo de Classificação - ANUAL
                </f:facet>
                <p:column headerText="TIPO CLASSIFICAÇÃO"
                    sortBy="#{linhaAnual.objeto}"
                    style="width:200px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="TIPO CLASSIFICAÇÃO" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaAnual.objeto}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="JAN" style="width:50px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="JAN" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaAnual.janeiro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="FEV" style="width:50px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="FEV" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaAnual.fevereiro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="MAR" style="width:50px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="MAR" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaAnual.marco}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="ABR" style="width:50px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="ABR" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaAnual.abril}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="MAI" style="width:50px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="MAI" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaAnual.maio}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="JUN" style="width:50px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="JUN" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaAnual.junho}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="JUL" style="width:50px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="JUL" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaAnual.julho}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="AGO" style="width:50px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="AGO" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaAnual.agosto}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="SET" style="width:50px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="SET" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaAnual.setembro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="OUT" style="width:50px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="OUT" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaAnual.outubro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="NOV" style="width:50px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="NOV" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaAnual.novembro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="DEZ" style="width:50px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="DEZ" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaAnual.dezembro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="TOTAL" style="width:100px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="TOTAL" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaAnual.totalLinha}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:columnGroup type="footer">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="1" style="text-align:right" footerText="Total Anual:" />
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesAnual[1]}" />
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesAnual[2]}" />
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesAnual[3]}" />
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesAnual[4]}" />
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesAnual[5]}" />
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesAnual[6]}" />
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesAnual[7]}" />
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesAnual[8]}" />
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesAnual[9]}" />
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesAnual[10]}" />
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesAnual[11]}" />
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesAnual[12]}" />
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.totalGeralAnual}" />
                    </p:row>
                </p:columnGroup>
            </p:dataTable>
            <br />
            <br />
            <p:dataTable id="dataTablePeriodo" var="linhaPeriodo"
                value="#{relatoriosMB.listaObjeto1}" editable="true"
                draggableColumns="true"
                rendered="#{not empty relatoriosMB.listaObjeto1}"
                widgetVar="tableClassPeriodo"
                filteredValue="#{relatoriosMB.filteredObjeto1}"
                emptyMessage="Não existem registros para o período informado."
                resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true">
                <f:facet name="header" style="text-allign:center">
                    Tabela Incidente - PERÍODO
                </f:facet>
                <p:column headerText="INCIDENTE"
                    sortBy="#{linhaPeriodo.objeto}"
                    style="width:200px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="INCIDENTE" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaPeriodo.objeto}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="JAN" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="JAN"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaPeriodo.janeiro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="FEV" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="FEV"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaPeriodo.fevereiro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="MAR" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.marco}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.marco}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="MAR"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaPeriodo.marco}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="ABR" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.abril}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.abril}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="ABR"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaPeriodo.abril}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="MAI" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.maio}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.maio}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="MAI"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaPeriodo.maio}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="JUN" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.junho}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.junho}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="JUN"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaPeriodo.junho}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="JUL" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.julho}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.julho}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="JUL"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaPeriodo.julho}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="AGO" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="AGO"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaPeriodo.agosto}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="SET" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="SET"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaPeriodo.setembro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="OUT" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.outubro}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.outubro}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="OUT"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaPeriodo.outubro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="NOV" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="NOV"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaPeriodo.novembro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="DEZ" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="DEZ"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaPeriodo.dezembro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="TOTAL" style="width:100px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="TOTAL"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaPeriodo.totalLinha}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:columnGroup type="footer">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="1" style="text-align:right"
                            footerText="Total Período:" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto1Periodo[1]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto1Periodo[2]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.marco}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto1Periodo[3]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.marco}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.abril}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto1Periodo[4]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.abril}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.maio}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto1Periodo[5]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.maio}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.junho}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto1Periodo[6]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.junho}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.julho}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto1Periodo[7]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.julho}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto1Periodo[8]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto1Periodo[9]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.outubro}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto1Periodo[10]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.outubro}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto1Periodo[11]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto1Periodo[12]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}"/>
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.totalGeralObjeto1Periodo}"/>
                    </p:row>
                </p:columnGroup>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:dataTable id="dataTableIncidentePeriodo"
                var="linhaIncidentePeriodo" value="#{relatoriosMB.listaObjeto2}"
                editable="true" draggableColumns="true"
                rendered="#{not empty relatoriosMB.listaObjeto2}"
                widgetVar="tableClassIncidentePeriodo"
                filteredValue="#{relatoriosMB.filteredObjeto2}"
                emptyMessage="Não existem registros para o período informado."
                resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true">
                <f:facet name="header" style="text-allign:center">
                    Tabela Grau do Incidente - PERÍODO
                </f:facet>
                <p:column headerText="GRAU DO INCIDENTE"
                    sortBy="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.objeto}"
                    style="width:200px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="GRAU DO INCIDENTE"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.objeto}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="JAN" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="JAN"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.janeiro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="FEV" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="FEV"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.fevereiro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="MAR" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.marco}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.marco}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="MAR"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.marco}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="ABR" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.abril}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.abril}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="ABR"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.abril}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="MAI" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.maio}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.maio}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="MAI"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.maio}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="JUN" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.junho}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.junho}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="JUN"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.junho}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="JUL" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.julho}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.julho}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="JUL"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.julho}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="AGO" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="AGO"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.agosto}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="SET" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="SET"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.setembro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="OUT" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.outubro}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.outubro}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="OUT"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.outubro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="NOV" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="NOV"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.novembro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="DEZ" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}" exportable="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="DEZ"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.dezembro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="TOTAL" style="width:100px;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="TOTAL"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{linhaIncidentePeriodo.totalLinha}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:columnGroup type="footer">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="1" style="text-align:right"
                            footerText="Total Incidente Período:" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto2Periodo[1]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto2Periodo[2]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.marco}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto2Periodo[3]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.marco}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.abril}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto2Periodo[4]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.abril}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.maio}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto2Periodo[5]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.maio}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.junho}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto2Periodo[6]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.junho}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.julho}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto2Periodo[7]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.julho}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto2Periodo[8]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto2Periodo[9]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.outubro}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto2Periodo[10]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.outubro}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto2Periodo[11]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}" />
                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}"
                            footerText="#{relatoriosMB.qtdTotalMesesObjeto2Periodo[12]}"
                            rendered="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}"/>
                        <p:column footerText="#{relatoriosMB.totalGeralObjeto2Periodo}" />
                    </p:row>
                </p:columnGroup>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <ui:include src="/paginas/admin/includes/rodape.xhtml" />

</p:layout>
```

---

Como podemos ver já tentei usar o rendered e o exportable, ambos com atributos boolean, mesmo assim não funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realizei a implementação do Custom Exporter, idem aos passos fornecidos no site [Steps to Custom Exporter](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/customExporter.jsf)

Após a implementação do modo customizado de exportação depurei o código padrão da exportação customizada, especificamente a classe "ExcelCustomExporter" e verifiquei que não havia consistência, quanto a tag exportable dos componentes footers. Depurando o código identifiquei o metodo que criava as colunas agrupadas do footer e inseri a consistência da tag exportable, do componente em uso. Alterei o metodo "tableColumnGroup", passando a criar a célula e inserir valor a ela quando o exportable fosse true.

Segue abaixo o código modificado:

```
protected void tableColumnGroup(Sheet sheet, DataTable table, String facetType) {
    ColumnGroup cg = table.getColumnGroup(facetType);
    List<UIComponent> headerComponentList = null;
    if (cg != null) {
        headerComponentList = cg.getChildren();
    }
    if (headerComponentList != null) {
        for (UIComponent component : headerComponentList) { 
            if (component instanceof org.primefaces.component.row.Row) {
                org.primefaces.component.row.Row row = (org.primefaces.component.row.Row) component;
                int sheetRowIndex = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
                Row xlRow = sheet.createRow(sheetRowIndex);
                int i = 0;
                for (UIComponent rowComponent : row.getChildren()) {
                    UIColumn column = (UIColumn) rowComponent;
                    String value = null;
                    if (facetType.equalsIgnoreCase("header")) {
                        value = column.getHeaderText();
                    } else {
                        value = column.getFooterText();

                    }
                    int rowSpan = column.getRowspan();
                    int colSpan = column.getColspan();

                    Cell cell = xlRow.getCell(i);

                    if (rowSpan > 1 || colSpan > 1) {
                        if (rowSpan > 1) {
                            cell = xlRow.createCell((short) i);
                            Boolean rowSpanFlag = false;
                            for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); j++) {
                                CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(j);
                                if (merged.isInRange(sheetRowIndex, i)) {
                                    rowSpanFlag = true;
                                }

                            }
                            if (!rowSpanFlag) {
                                cell.setCellValue(value);
                                cell.setCellStyle(facetStyle);
                                sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
                                        sheetRowIndex, //first row (0-based)
                                        sheetRowIndex + (rowSpan - 1), //last row  (0-based)
                                        i, //first column (0-based)
                                        i  //last column  (0-based)
                                ));
                            }
                        }
                        if (colSpan > 1) {
                            cell = xlRow.createCell((short) i);

                            for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); j++) {
                                CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(j);
                                if (merged.isInRange(sheetRowIndex, i)) {
                                    cell = xlRow.createCell((short) ++i);
                                }
                            }
                            cell.setCellValue(value);
                            cell.setCellStyle(facetStyle);
                            sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
                                    sheetRowIndex, //first row (0-based)
                                    sheetRowIndex, //last row  (0-based)
                                    i, //first column (0-based)
                                    i + (colSpan - 1)  //last column  (0-based)
                            ));
                            i = i + colSpan - 1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        //TODO TRATAR E VERIRIFICAR SE  O VALUE PODE SER EXIBIDO
                        if (column.isExportable()) {
                            cell = xlRow.createCell((short) i);
                            for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); j++) {
                                CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(j);
                                if (merged.isInRange(sheetRowIndex, i)) {
                                    cell = xlRow.createCell((short) ++i);
                                }
                            }
                            cell.setCellValue(value);
                            cell.setCellStyle(facetStyle);
                        }    
                    }
                    if (column.isExportable()) {
                        i++;
                    }   
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Gerei o relatório novamente, porém para um período de JAN a MAI, segue evidência:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]